# UIScrollView contentSize resizing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, contentsize

I am facing a weird problem and have been checking SO for solution but nothing yet so I figured I should ask. I have mainView (background colour White) inside a UIScrollView (background colour Green) and other views in the mainView. At the end of dynamically filling the views with data, I called

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, _v5.frame.size.height + _v5.frame.origin.y + 20);
```

where _v5 is the last view in the mainView in the scrollview. However, its looks like the mainView is not resizing to the Scrollview size and hence the views below the white are not receiving touches.[image] What am I doing wrong? Thanks

This is my viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.navigationItem.title = _type;
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 610);

addressTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleMap:)];
websiteTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleWebsite:)];

[_lblWebsite setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[_lblAddress setUserInteractionEnabled: YES];
[_lblWebsite addGestureRecognizer:websiteTap];
[_lblAddress addGestureRecognizer:addressTap];

        _txtName.text = object[@"name"];
        available =  object[@"sDate"];
        website = object[@"website"];
        anyinfo = object[@"info"];
        PFUser *my = object[@"owner"];
        organiser = my[@"username"];
        if (organiser.length > 0){
            _txtOrganiser.text = organiser;
        }
        address = object[@"address"];
        NSDate *date = object[@"sDate"];

        if (address.length > 0){
            _lblAddress.text = address;
        }
        else{
            _lblAddress.text= @"Not provided";
        }
        if (date){
            _lblOpen.text = [display stringFromDate:date];
        }
        if (website.length > 0){
            _lblWebsite.text = website;
        }
        else{
            _lblWebsite.text= @"Not provided";
        }

        if (anyinfo.length > 0){
            _txtInfo.text = anyinfo;
            [self updateFrames];
        }
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, _v5.frame.size.height + _v5.frame.origin.y + 20);
    } else {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showAlert) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
        NSLog(@"Error %@", error.description);
    }
}];

[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

and this is updateFrame

```
- (void) updateFrames{
_txtInfo.numberOfLines = 0;
_txtInfo.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
[_txtInfo sizeToFit];

_txtInfo.frame = CGRectMake(_txtInfo.frame.origin.x,_txtName.frame.origin.y + 10+ _txtName.frame.size.height, _txtInfo.frame.size.width, _txtInfo.frame.size.height);

_v1.frame = CGRectMake(_v1.frame.origin.x, _txtInfo.frame.origin.y + _txtInfo.frame.size.height +7, _v1.frame.size.width, _v1.frame.size.height);

_imgOrganiser.frame = CGRectMake(_imgOrganiser.frame.origin.x,_v1.frame.origin.y + 7, _imgOrganiser.frame.size.width, _imgOrganiser.frame.size.height);

_txtOrganiser.frame = CGRectMake(_txtOrganiser.frame.origin.x,_v1.frame.origin.y + 20, _txtOrganiser.frame.size.width, _txtOrganiser.frame.size.height);

_v2.frame = CGRectMake(_v2.frame.origin.x, _imgOrganiser.frame.origin.y + _imgOrganiser.frame.size.height +7, _v2.frame.size.width, _v2.frame.size.height);

_lblAddress.numberOfLines = 0;
_lblAddress.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
[_lblAddress sizeToFit];

_lblAddress.frame = CGRectMake(_lblAddress.frame.origin.x,_v2.frame.origin.y + 7, _lblAddress.frame.size.width, _lblAddress.frame.size.height);

_pin.frame = CGRectMake(_pin.frame.origin.x,_v2.frame.origin.y + 15, _pin.frame.size.width, _pin.frame.size.height);

_v3.frame = CGRectMake(_v3.frame.origin.x, _lblAddress.frame.origin.y + _lblAddress.frame.size.height +7, _v3.frame.size.width, _v3.frame.size.height);

_calender.frame = CGRectMake(_calender.frame.origin.x,_v3.frame.origin.y + 5, _calender.frame.size.width, _calender.frame.size.height);

_lblOpen.frame = CGRectMake(_lblOpen.frame.origin.x,_v3.frame.origin.y + 7, _lblOpen.frame.size.width, _lblOpen.frame.size.height);

_v4.frame = CGRectMake(_v4.frame.origin.x, _calender.frame.origin.y + _calender.frame.size.height +7, _v4.frame.size.width, _v4.frame.size.height);

_link.frame = CGRectMake(_link.frame.origin.x,_v4.frame.origin.y + 5, _link.frame.size.width, _link.frame.size.height);

_lblWebsite.frame = CGRectMake(_lblWebsite.frame.origin.x,_v4.frame.origin.y + 7, _lblWebsite.frame.size.width, _lblWebsite.frame.size.height);

_v5.frame = CGRectMake(_v5.frame.origin.x, _lblWebsite.frame.origin.y + _lblWebsite.frame.size.height +7, _v5.frame.size.width, _v5.frame.size.height);

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, _v5.frame.size.height + _v5.frame.origin.y + 20);}
```

Comment: where are setting the contentsize of scrollview ? in didLoad ?

Comment: On uiscrollview make `userInteractionEnabled = true`

Comment: @RahulMishra, yes at the viewDidLoad after loading my string and other content from the internet

Comment: @saintjab can you share your other code that is loading the view? Are you using constraints?

Comment: @SunilSharma, I don't think that would make any difference as the mainView is the parents of the views in Green and is that view size that is not resizing correctly.

Comment: Are you using auto layout? If so, read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

Comment: @thephatp, I have updated the question. Rob, am not using Autolayout

Comment: If I am not wrong u want mainview should occupy scrollview content size so u have to also update mainview frame size.

Comment: Its the same as the scrollView frame so if I update it, it will increase scrollView contentSize creating a big extra space below.